# File Compression in Java (Hadoop DefaultCodec) - how to make it human readable?

Tags: java, hadoop, compression

I have a file was compressed with `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec` I'd like to revert this file back to its original format - which is a string in JSON format.

I'm not too sure about how to use DefaultCodec's [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/DefaultCodec.html) to make this happen. Can someone give me an example of how this would look like? Here's what I have so far, I have no idea if I'm on the right track...

```
//grab my file (it's on S3)
S3Object fileOnS3 = s3Service.getObject("mys3bucket", "myfilename");

DefaultCodec codec = new DefaultCodec();
Decompressor decompressor = codec.createDecompressor();

//does the following line create a input stream that parses DefaultCodec into uncompressed form?
CompressionInputStream is = codec.createInputStream(fileOnS3.getDataInputStream(), decompressor);
//also, I have no idea what to do from here.
```

I'd like to store the uncompressed version in a `String` variable, since I know the file is a small one-liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the following:

1. Decompress the file using the hdfs shell command `-text` and unix shell, like that: 
   `hadoop dfs -text /path/on/hdfs/ > /local/path/for/local/raw/file`
2. Load the file using SequenceFileInputFormat for the input and set as output TextOutputFormat, using an identity mapper (and zero reducers).

I would go for the first option, especially if you say that the input file is a small string. If you want to load this file in a String variable, you can either load the file (which seems unnecessarily expensive), or store the output of `-text` command immediately in a String (skipping the part after `>`).